# Why Angular 4 replace bg URL before ng-build?

Tags: angular

**I've this code:**

```
body {
    background:url('./assets/bg.jpg');
}
```

**Before ng build :**

```
body {
    background: url(bg.ed946ca….jpg);
}
```

But img is in the right place **dist/assets/bg.jpg**

How to make that in css url did not change?

Comment: See related [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4517)

Comment: The Angular CLI does that. What's the problem you're facing?